# DataContractSerializer KnownType attribute not being respected?

Tags: wcf, datacontracts

I have a class that is decorated with a KnownType attribute with a type of the class.  Is this not allowed?

```
  [KnownType(typeof(Occ600UIConfig))]
    public class Occ600UIConfig 
    { }
```

If so, why is the DCS throwing the following exception?

> {"Error in line 1 position 387.
>   Element
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:Value'
>   contains data of the
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OCC600.Infrastructure.Dictionary.BusinessEntities:Occ600UIConfig'
>   data contract. The deserializer has no
>   knowledge of any type that maps to
>   this contract. Add the type
>   corresponding to 'Occ600UIConfig' to
>   the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the KnownTypeAttribute
>   attribute or by adding it to the list
>   of known types passed to
>   DataContractSerializer."}

Answer (score 4):

The `KnownType` attribute is used to define and "advertise" descendant classes of a base class that might also be used in a given context.

But your data class in WCF should be marked primarily with a `[DataContract]` attribute (and all members you want to include with a `[DataMember]` attribute):

```
[DataContract]
public class Occ600UIConfig 
{ }
```

If you don't have any inheritance hierarchies, you never need the KnownType attribute.